# Invoking a click on a class which is only used once

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use a loop and I'm getting freezing but no full crash.

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")

For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
 Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("name").ToString
 curElement.InvokeMember("click")
Next
```

In my case there should only be one div class name and I just want to invoke a click on it.

*edit-improved formatting*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround like so

```
For Each h As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("className").Equals("numeroCustomer") Then
            h.InnerText = loginid
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Hope this helps anybody with a similar problem.